# に->には / で->では etc

Tags: particles, particle-は

My question is kinda simple (I hope).

When somebody asks you, for example:

> 学生りょうにＴＶがありますか。

Can you answer:

> 台所**には**ありますが、部屋**には**ありません。

Or do you use:

> 台所**に**ありますが、部屋**には**ありません。

Can you also explain why that is, because I'm a little bit confused.
Does the same thing happen with で->では,  へ->へは?

Comment: Please remember that not everyone here is a native English speaker. I've updated your wording to make it more reader friendly.

Comment: See [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24804), [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39304), and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36908). There are probably more.

Answer (score 3):

Both work fine, but the focus of the answer would be different.

> 台所にありますが、部屋にはありません。

I think this answer would be more "direct". The question is "Is there a TV in the dorm?". A direct answer for this question would be "はい、テレビ**は**台所にあります。", or simply "台所にあります。" with テレビ as the implied topic. After directly answering the question, 部屋にはありません follows, which is an optional piece of information.

> 台所にはありますが、部屋にはありません。

This answer sounds like you have already noticed that the questioner actually wants a TV in his personal room. By adding the contrastive-wa in the first half of the sentence, you signal that "there is a TV in the kitchen, but that's probably not what you want". As a consequence, (テレビは)部屋にはありません gets more focused.

More simply put, 台所にあります sufficiently works as a straight answer to the question, whereas 台所に**は**あります sounds like "Yes, there is, *at least* in the kitchen".

Note that those explicit は after 台所に/部屋に are all contrastive-wa. The implied topic is always テレビ(は) throughout the conversation. In different contexts, は directly after ～に can safely work as a topic marker. See: [は、には、に。。。what is the difference between them?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36908/5010)