# Questions about possession phrases

Tags: grammar, possession

I'm asking here since I didn't manage to find a definitive answer to my questions.

**1. When should I use には and when は?**

The only thing I managed to find online is that は is used when a quantity is involved as in

> 私{わたし}は犬{いぬ}が[四匹]{よんひき}います。

while には is used in every other case. [[1]](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/existence-and-possession/)

However, the above phrase does not necessarily express possession. Out of context, it can simply mean "For me, there are four dogs", for example as an answer to "What's over there?".

**2. Why is it wrong to use the particle に instead of には or は?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/question-about-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-in-terms-of-emphasis

Comment: @kandyman: I don't think it's a duplicate. My question is more about grammar functions than emphasis nuances.